# Recuperar registro con la fecha más actual MySql

Tags: mysql

Tengo que recuperar de la tabla 'orden' el registro con la fecha más actual agrupados por el campo 'id_punto_suministro'.

En dicha tabla tengo dos registros con el mismo id_punto de suministro con dos fechas distintas:

Tabla orden:

```
id_orden |fecha_cancelacion    | id_punto_suministro

8704     | 2018-04-11 16:17:59 | 3558

8705     | 2018-04-16 16:23:25 | 3558
```

Querría que me recuperase solo el registro id_orden 8705.
Pero siempre me trae los dos a pesar de probar diferentes métodos.

La query que estoy usando es esta: ( tiene más filtros que no describí por no venir al caso )

```
SELECT o.id_orden, o.fecha_cancelacion, o.id_punto_suministro
    FROM orden  o
        INNER JOIN
            punto_suministro p ON o.id_punto_suministro = p.id_punto_suministro AND p.deleted=0
        INNER JOIN
            r_contrato_punto_suministro rc ON rc.id_punto_suministro = p.id_punto_suministro AND rc.deleted=0
        INNER JOIN
            contrato c ON c.id_contrato = rc.id_contrato AND c.deleted = 0
        INNER JOIN
            r_contrato_servicio rcs on rcs.id_contrato = c.id_contrato AND rcs.deleted =0
        INNER JOIN 
            servicio s on s.id_servicio = rcs.id_servicio AND s.deleted = 0
        INNER JOIN
            tipo_servicio ts on ts.id_tipo_servicio = s.id_tipo_servicio AND ts.deleted = 0
    WHERE p.impago = 0      
        AND ts.id_tipo_servicio = 2 
        AND o.status = 'OrdenWorkflow/cancelada' 
        AND o.motivo_cancelacion = 'Impago, scoring'          
        AND o.fecha_cancelacion is not null 
        AND o.id_tipo = 2 
        AND o.deleted=0 
        AND o.fecha_cancelacion = (
            select fecha_cancelacion
            from orden t2 
            where o.id_orden = t2.id_orden 
            AND fecha_cancelacion  >= date_add(current_date(),INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
            group by id_punto_suministro
            ORDER BY fecha_cancelacion ASC);
```

Pero me trae los dos registros. Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Creo que es por el where o.id_orden = t2.id_orden de t2, pero para aclarar te pregunto: quieres que te traiga la más reciente de una orden con un punto en especifico no?, tal vez intentanto hacer max en el campo fecha te sea más útil

Comment: select max(fecha_cancelacion)
            from orden t2 
            where o.id_orden = t2.id_orden 
            group by id_punto_suministro
            ORDER BY fecha_cancelacion ASC

Comment: Buenas, zerocool, si pongo max en la subquery obtengo el mismo resultado, si lo pongo en la select principal me trae la fecha mas alta pero con el id_orden 8704, necesito que sea el id_ordem 8705 con su fecha. Gracias por contestar

Comment: Creo que hay varios problemas, pero como dices que hay más filtros no sé... pero a simple vista, tanto el `GROUP BY` como el `max(fecha_cancelacion)` deberían estar en la consulta principal, no en la sub-consulta. Tampoco entiendo cual es el sentido de esa sub-consulta ... Tampoco existe en ninguna parte un `WHERE id_punto_suministro = 3558`... En cuanto a que quieres un solo registro, otra opción sería usar `LIMIT 1` para que te traiga un solo registro.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que pasa es que el registro principal vendría de la limitante de la subconsulta, el problema en realidad viene porque la fecha está en la orden... y como bien dices debería ser la búsqueda por el id_punto pero de nuevo buscar solo por id_punto en esa tabla no le daría bien la fecha.

Comment: Buenas A. Cedano. Los filtros de la query principal son temas de exclusion de otras órdenes. Si pongo el group by y el max en la principal me devuelve el id_orden 8704, con la fecha del 8705 ( 8704 | 2018-04-16 16:23:25 | 3558 ). El id_punto de suministro no puede ser fijo pues hay N órdenes a un mismo id_punto_suministro. La idea es que de los que sean del mismo punto_suministro me traiga el registro con la fecha más actual.  Gracias por contestar.

Comment: La consulta es tan extensa que no llego a entender bien la situación. ¿Si pruebas la sub-consulta lo más simplificada posible, te trae los resultados esperados de ella? En casos de consultas extensas a veces conviene hacer eso, irlas aplicando por partes, así verás dónde está el error.

Comment: haciendo solo la subconsulta ( select id_orden, fecha_cancelacion
from orden t2 
WHERE fecha_cancelacion  >= date_add(current_date(),INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
AND id_punto_suministro = 3558
group by id_punto_suministro
ORDER BY fecha_cancelacion asc; )  me trae siempre el 8704, independientemente que el order by lo ponga a desc / asc.

Comment: Es que la cosa es así, debes buscar el punto en base a la orden y luego  es cuando puedes buscar la fecha mayor de las ordenes en base a ese punto, si me entiendes?

Comment: Eres un crack zerocool!
subquery ( select max(fecha_cancelacion)
            from orden t2 
            where o.id_punto_suministro = t2.id_punto_suministro 
            AND fecha_cancelacion  >= date_add(current_date(),INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
            group by id_punto_suministro
            ORDER BY fecha_cancelacion ASC ).
Cambie where o.id_orden = t2.id_orden por where o.id_punto_suministro = t2.id_punto_suministro y lo recupera bien!. Voy a probar que siga omitiendo el resto de casuísticas que necesito y os comentaré, pero así a voz y pronto tiene buena pinta.Muchas gracias zerocool.

Comment: Croe que así estaría más simple: revisa si te sirve:  

 o.fecha = (select max(fecha) 
               from orders o2 where o2.id_punto = o.id_punto
             );